# Undefined reference to extern class?

Tags: c++

When using extern on classes it is giving me undefined reference, but when I make the function I'm calling from that class "static" it works fine.

Is there anyway to do it without using a static member function?

My test code:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        void print() { std::clog << "print()" << std::endl; }
};

extern MyClass *g_myClass;

int main()
{
    g_myClass->print();
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `_g_myClass'
```

In the actual code I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00465af2 in std::_Rb_tree<Irc::Config::Config_t, std::pair<Irc::Config::Config
_t const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Irc::Config::Config_t const, s
td::string> >, std::less<Irc::Config::Config_t>, std::allocator<std::pair<Irc::C
onfig::Config_t const, std::string> > >::_M_begin (this=0x0)
    at c:/qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tre
e.h:482
482           { return static_cast<_Link_type>(this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent
); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00465af2 in std::_Rb_tree<Irc::Config::Config_t, std::pair<Irc::Config::Co
nfig_t const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Irc::Config::Config_t cons
t, std::string> >, std::less<Irc::Config::Config_t>, std::allocator<std::pair<Ir
c::Config::Config_t const, std::string> > >::_M_begin (this=0x0)
    at c:/qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tre
e.h:482
#1  0x0046596b in std::_Rb_tree<Irc::Config::Config_t, std::pair<Irc::Config::Co
nfig_t const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Irc::Config::Config_t cons
t, std::string> >, std::less<Irc::Config::Config_t>, std::allocator<std::pair<Ir
c::Config::Config_t const, std::string> > >::find (this=0x0, __k=@0x22fe40)
    at c:/qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tre
e.h:1421
#2  0x0045ec7c in std::map<Irc::Config::Config_t, std::string, std::less<Irc::Co
nfig::Config_t>, std::allocator<std::pair<Irc::Config::Config_t const, std::stri
ng> > >::find (this=0x0, __x=@0x22fe40)
    at c:/qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_map
.h:659
#3  0x0040d376 in Irc::Config::getInt (this=0x0, arg=1) at configreader.cpp:72
#4  0x00405656 in Irc::Database::connect (this=0x483300) at database.cpp:30
#5  0x00406965 in main (argc=1, argv=0x3d3e18) at main.cpp:26
(gdb)
```

Comment: `this = 0x0` should tell you something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate an instance first, and make sure that you have a non-`extern` definition of `g_myClass` among your object files.

Answer (score 7):

When you write:

```
extern MyClass *g_myClass;
```

you are **declaring** a pointer. This make the compiler work, but not the linker that also needs a **definition** of it.

Somewhere in your code you have to insert:

```
MyClass *g_myClass;
```

(and allocating it, I suppose).

Comment: +1 for mentionning the difference in the compilation/link process

Comment: The definition is needed only if the pointer is being used (as in OP) else not required

Comment: @Fallen as I said, you need to allocate it too.

Comment: What do you mean? like "new MyClass"?

Comment: good luck in using a pointer without having first initialized to an existing object :)

Answer (score 1):

What can be extern is the object, not the cass. What's missing here is the definition of the object you're declaring extern.

You should do :

```
extern MyClass *g_myClass; // where you want to expose the existence of g_myClass, often in a header


MyClass *g_myClass; // the real definition of your object, in one (and only one) compilation unit  (cpp file).
```

The first one declare the object, the second one defines it. In your example you declare that the object exists without defining it anywhere.